# How to join previous row to each row on multiple columns match in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

I'd like to have one SQL statement in which I'll get for each row the first previous row (previous because of ID, datetime or anything else) which match on multiple columns. Any ideas or I have to use DB+app combination?

example table:

```
id  col1  col2  col3
1   1     2     3
2   1     2     4
3   1     2     5
4   2     2     1
```

result (matched cols are col1 and col2, order by id):

```
id  col1  col2  col3  priorID  priorCol1  priorCol2  priorCol3
1   1     2     3     n        n          n          n
2   1     2     4     1        1          2          3
3   1     2     5     2        1          2          4
4   2     2     1     n        n          n          n
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using SQL function like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION my_func (idx INT) 
 RETURNS INT
 READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
 RETURN (
  SELECT t2.ID 
  FROM test AS t1 
  LEFT JOIN test AS t2 
  ON (t1.COL1=t2.COL1 AND t1.COL2=t2.COL2 AND t1.ID > t2.ID) 
  WHERE t1.ID = idx
  ORDER BY t2.ID DESC
  LIMIT 1
 );
    END$$

DELIMITER;
```

And then use it in your SQL query like

```
SELECT * FROM test AS t1 
LEFT JOIN test as t2 ON (t2.ID=my_func(t1.ID))
ORDER BY t1.ID
```

Don't forget to uses proper indexes otherwise you could easily create a very slow bottleneck here.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, works like a charm. Thank you very much. I cannot give you +1 as I have low reputation here. :-(